# How to cancel the action of a selected button (QPushButton) when a new button is clicked in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

`class MainWindow(QWidget):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()

```
    self.setWindowTitle("Window")
    self.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 400)

    self.Function()

def Function(self):
    xpos = 10

    for i in range(5):
    
        button = QPushButton("".format(i+1), self)
        button.setGeometry(xpos, 150, 50, 50 )
        xpos = xpos + 50
        button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")
        button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i+1: self.function(i))     
        button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=button : self.color(i))     

     
def function(self, i):
    print(i)

def color(self, i):
    i.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : black; border-radius : 25px")`i am new to this sort of programming, and
```

i am trying to create a row of buttons (number of buttons are given as input) that are aligned side by side. A button (QPushButton) that is once clicked should take on a color, and when an other button is clicked, the previous action should be canceled and the new selected button must be colored.

I was able to use the "btn.clicked.connect(...)" method to make the selected button get colored. But when the other buttons are clicked the previous ones keep the color without going into default.
How do i have to do it correctly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've declared `button` it's hard to refer to it later on. I can think of two ways around this:

1. put your buttons in a list
2. put your buttons in a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html)

### put your buttons in a list

```
class MainWindow(QWidget): 

    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window")
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 400)
        self.Function()

    def Function(self):
        xpos = 10

    self.button_list = []

    for i in range(5):
        button = QPushButton("{}".format(i+1), self)
        button.setGeometry(xpos, 150, 50, 50 )
        xpos = xpos + 50
        button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")
        self.button_list.append(button)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i+1: self.function(i))     
        button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=button : self.color(i))     
     
    def function(self, i):
        print(i)

    def color(self, i):
        bnum = int(i.text())
        for idx, button in enumerate(self.button_list):
            if idx+1 == bnum:
                button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : black; border-radius : 25px")
            else:
                button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")
```

### put your buttons in a QButtonGroup

```
class MainWindow(QWidget): 

    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window")
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 400)
        self.Function()

    def Function(self):
        xpos = 10

    self.button_group = QButtonGroup()

    for i in range(5):
        button = QPushButton("{}".format(i+1), self)
        button.setGeometry(xpos, 150, 50, 50 )
        xpos = xpos + 50
        button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")
        self.button_group.addButton(button, id=i+1)
        self.button_group.idClicked.connect(self.color)
        self.button_group.idClicked.connect(self.function)
     
    # arguments have changed bid is the button id assigned in addButton
    def function(self, bid):
        print(self.button_group.button(bid))

    def color(self, bid):
        bcount = len(self.button_group.buttons())
        for i in range(bcount)
            if i+1 == bid:
                button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : black; border-radius : 25px")
            else:
                button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")
```

### a little more efficient...

Both cases as I've coded them are a little kludgy since they go though ALL of the buttons every time you click ONE button. If you were to save the last button pressed, then you would only have to modify the last button and the current button:

```
btn = self.button_group.button(self.last_bid)
btn.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")

btn = self.button_group.button(bid)
btn.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : black; border-radius : 25px")

self.last_bid = bid
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I tried the method with button in a list. Whenever I run the code it says : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. How to prevent this?

Comment: Ahh. This problem comes from `"".format(i+1)` in the original code which will give an empty string. I think what you wanted was `"{}".format(i+1)` which will give a number formatted as a string. I have corrected code and that error should go away.

Comment: it worked!!! Is there another way then not to show the digits inside the buttons?

Comment: Well, you could stuff the assigned digits into the `objectName` property when you create the button, i.e. `button =QPushButton(objectName = "{}".format(i+1)`. And replace `bnum = int(i.text())` with `bnum = int(i.objectName())`. Or you could make the text the same color as the background.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is by using the self.sender() method.
This will tell you which button was clicked. Then you can loop through the other buttons and change their style sheet to some default color.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
   
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.color_buttons)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.color_buttons)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.color_buttons)
    
        self.button_list = [self.pushButton_1, self.pushButton_2, self.pushButton_3]

        self.button_default_css  = "background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);"
        self.button_selected_css = "background-color: rgb(102, 176, 54);"
    

    def color_buttons(self):
        print(f"\nButton Pressed : {self.sender().objectName()}")
        for button in self.button_list:
            if button == self.sender():
                button.setStyleSheet(self.button_selected_css)
            else:
                button.setStyleSheet(self.button_default_css)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry just realizing the other part of this problem. I assume you're running a thread after pressing one of the buttons otherwise you wouldn't be able to click another button on the GUI since the GUI will freeze up until it's done with whatever the first button did. If that's the case then you will need some kind of flag in the thread like "running" and throughout the code in the thread you will need to sprinkle in some "if not running: return" or something like that to make the thread stop.

Comment: self.sender. That's a trick I didn't know about. It's worth pointing out that it only works if objectName() is set. If you're using Qt Designer/Creator, objectNames in ui will all be set, but if you make the layout programmatically, you'll have to set the objectName yourself in the code (something you might not normally think about).

Comment: normally self.sender() will give you the actual QPushButton object I just used the objectname() for the sake of printing it as proof

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.clicked.disconnect()
```

The above code probably will work for you. For the further questions you are going to ask, do not forget to add your sample code:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example